# REST API 500 Server error posting a message using Circuit by Unify

Tags: rest, circuit-sdk

I'm trying to post a message using the Client-Credentials Grant flow (https://circuit.github.io/oauth.html#client_credentials) But keep getting

```
'{"errorDescription":"n/a","errorCode":"500"}'
```

Which isn't very useful (no useful information in the headers either)

I'm using the following python code, using the requests library

```
import requests

conv_id = "conv-uuid-here"
client_id = "client-id-here"
client_secret = "client-secret-here"
token = requests.request("POST", "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/oauth/token",
                         headers={
                             "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                         },
                         data={
                             "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                             "scope": "ALL",
                         },
                         auth=(client_id, client_secret)
                         ).json()["access_token"]

r = requests.request("POST", "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations/{conv_id}/messages".format(conv_id=conv_id),
                 **{
                     "json": {
                         "content": "this is a test",
                         "convId": conv_id
                     },
                     "headers": {
                         "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
                         "Content-Type": "application/json"
                     }
                 })
```

So if you replace `token =` with a token retrieved from the swagger api docs (https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/swagger/ui/index.html)
it works just fine (But it posts from the logged in user, not the bot).

So are there certain endpoints that don't work when using different methods of authentication, and if so, where can I find documentation on it? (Client credentials grant vs implicit grant, I can't use an implicit grant since I do not have an redirect url)

Is there any way to get more information back from the server on this 500 error to help debug?

Thanks

Comment: There has been some recent enhancements on circuitsandbox.net in regards to traffic shaping which caused some intermittent authentication errors. I have just tried your code example and successfully posted the message. I have seen the 500 error as well earlier and will see if we can improve the error message for this case. Can you please try again and check if its working now?

Comment: It looks like I'm still getting the 500 error. Do you think my app account state is broken somehow? @RogerUrscheler

Comment: The issue has been identified and is limited to Client Credentials Grant type (bots) and only for the REST API (nodejs SDK is fine).
A fix will be available early next week.